# Fast PWM and Atmega1280

Tags: atmega, pwm

Hello I have some problems to understand how to bind a Timer to a Pin and because of that my code isn't running...

```
#include <avr/io.h>


void init_PWM(void)
{
    TCCR0A|=(1<<WGM00)|(1<<WGM01)|(1<<COM0A1)|(1<<CS00);


    //Set OC0 PIN as output. It is  PB3 on ATmega16 ATmega32

    DDRB|=(1<<PB7);
}

void setPWM(uint8_t duty)
{
   OCR0A = duty;
}


void main (void)
{
   uint8_t brightness = 0;
   init_PWM();

   for (brightness=0; brightness<=255; brightness++)
   {
      setPWM(brightness);
      _delay_ms(100);
   }
}
```

My problem is how to assign the timer to PB7 ?

My goal is blinking LED on PB7 with FastPWM Mode...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

for mega1280 is CS00 in TCCR0B and not in TCCR0A

```
void init_PWM(void) {
    TCCR0A|=(1<<WGM00)|(1<<WGM01)|(1<<COM0A1);
    TCCR0B|=(1<<CS00);
    DDRB|=(1<<PB7);
}
```